# Variable sized packet

Tags: c++, networking, simulation, ns-3

I am trying to define a packet whose length is determined during an ns-3 simulation (think of it as a packet sent on the downlink containing schedule information whose length depends on the number of nodes in the network which can join/leave the network during simulation). Does anyone have any idea how I could approach this?

Answer (score 0):

The traditional solution is to send the length first, followed by the data:

```
+------------+---------------------+
| uint32_t n | n - 4 bytes of data |
+------------+---------------------+
```

To decode, read the first four bytes, and then use the value in those bytes to determine how much more data there is.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is how to define such a packet which is like a variable sized array. Notice that new fields are added to the packet based on its length? how should they be defined?

Comment: @user2225868: Read the data into a buffer and parse it? I don't know, that's pretty standard C++ programming...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest introduction on how to do this is http://www.nsnam.org/support/faq/miscellaneous/#table

In practice, if you want to extend this code to store a variable-sized data structure, you can do this:

```
class MyHeader : public Header
{
public:
  // new methods
  void AppendData (uint16_t data);
  std::vector<uint16_t> GetData (void) const;

  static TypeId GetTypeId (void);
  // overridden from Header
  virtual uint32_t GetSerializedSize (void) const;
  virtual void Serialize (Buffer::Iterator start) const;
  virtual uint32_t Deserialize (Buffer::Iterator start);
  virtual void Print (std::ostream &os) const;
private:
  std::vector<uint16_t> m_data;
};
```

I will skip the obvious GetData/AppendData methods. Instead, we can focus on the Serialize/Deserialize methods:

```
uint32_t 
MyHeader::GetSerializedSize (void) const
{
  // two bytes of data to store
  return m_data.size() * 2;
}
void 
MyHeader::Serialize (Buffer::Iterator start) const
{
  start.WriteHtonU32(GetSerializedSize());
  for (std::vector<uint16_t>::const_iterator i = m_data.begin(); i != m_data.end(); i++) 
    {
      start.WriteHtonU16 (*i);
    }
}
uint32_t 
MyHeader::Deserialize (Buffer::Iterator start)
{
  uint32_t len = start.ReadNtohU32 ();
  for (uint32_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    m_data.append(start.ReadNtohU16())
  }
  return 4+len*2;
}
```